# nested Owned Type not saved when Updating in the database

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have following classes:

Order:

```cs
public class Order {
  private Order()
  {
      //some code to initialise object
  }
  //more properties
  public Prepayment Prepayment { get; private set; }
  //more methods and properties
}
```

Prepayment:

```cs
public class Prepayment:ValueObject<Prepayment>
{
    private Prepayment()
    {   
    }

    public Money AmountPrepaid { get; private set; }
    public bool HasPrepaymentBeenTaken => AmountPrepaid.Amount > 0;
}
```

Money:

```
public class Money {
        private Money()
        {
        }
        private Money(decimal amount)
        : this()
        {
            Amount = amount;
        }
        public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
}
```

Then I the Order class is mapped to the database in following way:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                .OwnsOne(x => x.Prepayment,
                    prepayment =>
                    {
                        prepayment.OwnsOne(x => x.AmountPrepaid,
                            amountPrepaid =>
                            {
                                amountPrepaid.Property(x => x.Amount)
                                    .HasColumnName("PrepaymentAmount")
                                    .HasColumnType("decimal(7,2)");
                            });
                    });
```

Repository code to SaveChanges:

```
public async Task<int> SaveAsync(Order order)
{
    if (order.Id == 0)
    {
        await _context.AddAsync(order);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Update(order);
    }

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Please understand, I removed all the not important properties from the code, to make the example more clear.

Above code works well for `INSERT` scenario, where Prepayment -> Money -> Amount is properly saved into the database. `UPDATE` though doesn't seem to be reflected in the database.

Please note, I have quite a few Owned Types in that model, and all of them are working well. The only difference as far as I can say is the fact that `Prepayment` property has another nested Owned type - `Money`.

`Order` class object passed to repository, is first pulled from the database, then changes are applied on that instance, and finally saved back to the database. Other properties like `Customer` not mentioned in the example, is also a `OwnedType` and `UPDATE` works as expected.

Just in case - the code used to retrieve the object prior to update:

```
public async Task<Order> GetOrderByIdAsync(int orderId)
{
    var result = (from order in _context.Orders
                  where order.Id == orderId
                  select order).Include(x => x.OrderLines);

    return await result.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

The exact version of Entity Framework Core I am using is: 2.2.0

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

### EDIT:

The code that updates the data looks like this:

```
public async Task<int> Handle(EditOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var order = await _orderRepository.GetOrderByIdAsync(request.Id);

    var customer = new Customer(
        request.FirstName,
        request.LastName,
        request.TelephoneNumber);

    var prepayment = new Prepayment(
        Money.SomeMoney(
            request.PrepaymentAmount
            )
        );

    order.ApplyChanges(
            request.UserId, 
            request.AdditionalInformation,
            collectionDate,
            customer,
            prepayment);

    await _orderRepository.SaveAsync(order);

    return order.Id;
}
```

And part of the ApplyChanges method that sets prepayment:

```
private void SetPrepayment(Prepayment prepayment)
{
    Prepayment = prepayment ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(prepayment));
}
```

Comment: Is the object pulled from the **same** db context instance used for `Update`? And what and how exactly is modified? All these private constructors/property setters make me think you are doing something unusual / not expected/supported by EF Core. Providing a small but full repro (mcve) would help identifying the issue.

Comment: Yes it is. I tried to do _context.Attach before update as well, but no change at all. Also private setters are working well, there is a Method on the Orders object that changes state of Prepayment. I have also another owned types on the Order class that behave properly, the dofference is nesting as far as I can tell. Prepayment has nested Money object in it.

Comment: If it's pulled from the same db context instance, it's *already attached*, so neither `Attach` nor `Update` normally is needed. And of course you have some mutating methods, the question was what they do.  In simple words, do they modify properties of the existing objects or create new objects? DDD "value objects" look very suspicious. Looks like [mcve] is needed.

Comment: I got you now, it is just assigning new Prepayment object to the Order value. Prepayment or Money doesn't even have Id field as they are Owned Types. As a compare, there is another Property Customer - that have private setter of ValueObject<Customer> and also sets a new instance of Customer every time - and that one works as expected. I will try to prepare an example later in the afternoon if I have a chance. I've now put the Handler code - that saves changes and apply updates

Comment: EF Core does not work well with "value" (immutable) objects, because the change tracking works with "reference identity". "Owned entity types" are still "entity" types by EF Core terminology, so the same reference tracking rules apply. Consider reading [Current shortcomings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings) and basically the whole Owned Types topic - looks like the conclusion is that value objects cannot be implemented with owned types.

Comment: I don't think any of the shortcomings apply to this case. Especially the other property - Customer works well. Please note I have also new Instance of Prepayment and Money objects passed to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189015/discussion-between-madoxdev-and-ivan-stoev).

Comment: There is a [bug in ef core 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12118) that prevents owned-owned type from update. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Yeah, disabling tracking as given in the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue has something in common with the nested owned entity type.

But the general problem is that the way you are using owned entity types is violating the EF Core rules, thus the behavior is undefined - sometimes it might work, sometimes not, sometimes even throw exceptions etc.

Owned entity types cannot be used to implement value objects, because even they are "owned", by EF Core terminology they are still "entities" (with hidden shadow PK), so they are tracked *by reference* and follow the same rules as other entity references -most importantly, there must be only one object instance per defining navigation PK.

In short, they are supposed to be allocated once and then mutated via their primitive properties. While what are you doing is mutating the references with immutable objects.

It's hard to give you good advice because of the aforementioned EF Core rule violations. The only working workaround is to make sure all original object references are not tracked by the context.

For instance, if `GetOrderByIdAsync` implementation uses `AsNoTracking` query, hence neither `order` nor `order.Prepayment` and `order.Prepayment.AmountPrepaid` instances are tracked by the `_context`, then `_context.Update(order)` will work.

It will also work if you manually detach them before calling `ApplyChanges` (requires access to the db context):

```
_context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.Entry(order.Prepayment).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.Entry(order.Prepayment.AmountPrepaid).State = EntityState.Detached;

order.ApplyChanges(...);

await _orderRepository.SaveAsync(order); // _context.Update(order);
```

Looks like `AsNoTracking` is the better option. You can make it default for all queries by setting `ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;` inside your db context constructor and use `AsTracking()` where needed.

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you. There is an issue on Github to maybe come up with a better approach. I am sure nHibernate is dealing with those Value Objects and DDD concepts better. Thank you for all the explenation!

Comment: Hmmm, this seems [to be a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12118), not a not supported case.

Comment: Update: This *appears* to have been fixed in new EF versions, at least for me. Regular tracking queries + nothing detached. No workaround required, you can simply replace the entities.